# How long after finishing meal will vitamins be well absorbed?

Tags: micronutrients, supplement, time-of-day, meal, dissolve

How long after finishing a meal will taking vitamin supplements work well (the vitamins will be absorbed in a sufficient amount) if the recommendation states that it should be taken with food?